# Different types of variables in Lua are confusing

Tags: lua

It's not "Parameter" or "Argument", but  "variable function" and "variable arguments", "variable number of arguments". I found this confusing and want to know what are these things.

I found it inside Programming in Lua First Edition 5.1

> An important use for unpack is in a generic call mechanism. A generic call mechanism allows you to call any function, with any arguments, dynamically. In ANSI C, for instance, there is no way to do that. You can declare a function that receives a variable number of arguments (with stdarg.h) and you can call a variable function, using pointers to functions. However, you cannot call a function with a variable number of arguments: Each call you write in C has a fixed number of arguments and each argument has a fixed type. In Lua, if you want to call a variable function f with variable arguments in an array a, you simply write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That paragraph is rather sloppily written, construing "parameter" and "argument" and uses the bespoke term "variable function" for what I assume was intended to be "[variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic)", which is what C actually has.

In any case, the point I believe this paragraph is intended to convey is the following.

C has variadic functions: functions which can take a variable number of parameters. This means you can call them with an arbitrary number of arguments, which the function will then process according to its needs. However, the sequence of arguments given to a function is always hard-coded at the call site. You cannot build a runtime list of values and pass each value to a variadic function as multiple distinct arguments, such that the function would see each value from the list as a separate parameter. At least, you cannot do this without hard-coding the length of the list at the call site.

In Lua, you can do this, taking a list of "arbitrary" length (arguments do have a maximum limit) and calling a function such that the function sees each value in the list as a distinct parameter. No matter the number of values in the list, `f(unpack(list))` will pass each value as a separate parameter to `f`.

Comment: can u explain more clearly about "variable number of parameters"? Everything else is awesome

Comment: and how to use unpack because some Edition 1 codes are outdated. This is how i use it `function new(a)
return a
end
print(new(unpack({1, "bruh", 3})))`

Comment: @BlaztOne: `new` is not a variadic function; it takes exactly one parameter. So what exactly do you expect to happen when you pass it 3 arguments? It ignores the other two.

Comment: @BlaztOne: You cited a Lua 5.1 book. If you're not using Lua 5.1, then you should state what version of Lua you *are* using.

Comment: i'm using lua 5.3, but this isn't lua 5.1 book, this is [lua 5.0 book](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html)

Comment: @BlaztOne: You said "I found it inside Programming in Lua First Edition 5.1". So which is it, 5.0 or 5.1? Also, put the Lua version you're *actually using* in your question.

Comment: wait, I thought the main question is: " what is variable number of parameter", but now i think i need to know what is variable number of arguments too...

Comment: also can u give me an example about something like "variadic function" in lua? the examples in "Programming in Lua Edition 1" are outdated. Or maybe Lua 5.3 no longer can't use anything like variadic function?

Comment: "*I thought the main question is: " what is variable number of parameter", but now i think i need to know what is variable number of arguments too...*" The term "parameter" refers to what a function takes in its definition. The term "argument" refers to the expression(s) that the function is given when it is called. The Lua reference manual does a good job of keeping these two terms straight. The page you linked to is talking about passing a variable number of *arguments*.

Comment: **Variadic functions are functions that may be called with different number of arguments**. [My luck is over heaven](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic). I don't even think variadic arguments site will explain variadic functions better than the variadic functions site lol this is hillarious